# Prove this binomial identity

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Prove the binomial identity
$$\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n}(-1)^i {n\choose{i}}{2i\choose{n}}=(-2)^n$$

Comment: It seems to work perfectly $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{2}(-1)^i {2\choose{i}}{2i\choose{2}}=(-1)^0 {2\choose{0}}{0\choose{2}}+(-1)^1 {2\choose{1}}{2\choose{2}}+(-1)^2 {2\choose{2}}{4\choose{2}}=0-2+6=4$

Comment: Works for me. I think you might have inputted it wrongly, Donald.

Comment: As a suggestion, given the well known identity, $\sum\limits_{i=0}^ni\binom{n}{i}=n2^{n-1}$, one method could be proving that your series can be transformed into $\sum\limits_{i=0}^n\frac{2i(-1)^n}{n}\binom{n}{i}$.

Comment: @Jam Yeah sorry, my bad, brain freeze. It does work.

Comment: @Jam It is very interested because your suggestion doesn't use generation functions and looks elementary for me. But I did these things long ago. How can I transform my series to your $\sum\limits_{i=0}^n\frac{2i(-1)^n}{n}\binom{n}{i}$?

Comment: @xyz On closer inspection, it doesn't look like there's an easy way of transforming the series. So Donald's method or induction would probably be the better alternative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the notation $[x^n]: f(x)$ to represent the coefficient of $x^n$ in the function $f(x)$.
So for example
\begin{eqnarray*}
\binom{2i}{n} = [x^n]: (1+x)^{2i}. 
\end{eqnarray*}

\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{i=0}^{n} (-1)^i \binom{n}{i} \binom{2i}{n} &=& [x^n] : \sum_{i=0}^{n} (-1)^i \binom{n}{i} (1+x)^{2i} \\
&=& [x^n] : (1- (1+x)^{2} )^n \\ 
&=& [x^n] :(-1)^n (2x +x^2 )^n\\ &=&(-2)^n. 
\end{eqnarray*}